# Why can't I launch activities via reference?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

The Android Developer Guide states that activities are launched via Intents:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

For Fragments, the usual way to display it on the screen is as follows:

```
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Why is it that in one case I have to specify a class, and in the other an object? I.e., I would like to use something like

```
Activity nextActivity = new SignInActivity();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, nextActivity);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: You can use (custom) action(s). No?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Activity` lifecycle is managed by Android whereas `Fragment` lifecycle is tied to the Activity in which it is contained.

As mentioned, `Activity` lifecycle is managed by Android. This is required, among other things, for Android to manage the system resources and also to take care of the back stack.

`Fragment`, on the other hand, was introduced to modularize and better organize the UI for devices with different sizes. According the the documentation:

> Starting with HONEYCOMB, `Activity` implementations can make use of the
>   `Fragment` class to better modularize their code, build more
>   sophisticated user interfaces for larger screens, and help scale their
>   application between small and large screens.

To answer the latter part of your question, you can indeed pass the results of an activity to a second activity. But you should never create an instance of an `Activity` class for that. The right way is to use the `startActivityForResult()` and send the resulting value to  the destination activity through the `Intent`.

Comment: +1 That's why creating an Explicit-constructor (with params) for activities and fragments is not a good idea.

Comment: Can you explain how the requirement for lifecycle management (`onCreate`,`onResume`, etc.) is tied to the requirement that the activity must be instanciated by the system?

Comment: It has to do more with the design of Android. Android recognizes only the Activities / Services .. that are declared in the manifest. AFAIU, otherwise it would be cumbersome and unproductive for it to monitor every object created to check if it belongs to one of the above classes. So a user-created object is considered as a normal Java object. Hence it would not be possible for Android to manage its lifecycle. The [Activities developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) should give you an overview of how the system controls the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

While adding fragment,  you are already specifying where exactly to insert that fragment into. So, the ideal way is to,

1. Create your fragment.
2. Insert into a layout of your current activity.
3. Use transactions to remove/manage your fragments, added to the current activity.

In no way, you could launch or use just a fragment, without attaching it to an existing activity.

Answer (score 0):

Android handles Activity life cycle by itself. Just look at the methods of Activity class, they're just like a *fill in the blanks*. Android calls the shots here. Through these methods it just ask *if* you want to do something when this activity is created, resumed, paused etc.

The reasons for Android handling activity life cycle internally, are many:

1. Properly setting up an Activity involves lots of boiler plate code, better let system do it for you. The whole `Context` and `window management` is set up for you behind the scenes. Imagine the amount of extra work, if you had to do it for every Activity you created.
2. Activities are shared, home screen and other applications might want to launch/use them. How would be this possible if they have to call `new MyActivity()` of some obscure package ? . This is why Activities and other externally invokable components must be declared in application manifest.
3. Activities from many applications can be parts of an android *task* ( a piece of work from user's perspective). And are automatically placed/removed/re-arranged on a back-stack. Again, its better Android manage their creation and destruction rather than developers messing with this whole setup.
4. All user cares is that an Activity must show up when asked for, and just get out of the way if user navigates somewhere else. Android enforces this. Making an Activity appear on its own, or refuse to go away, just because its allowed to be programmed that way, is unacceptable.

Now Fragments , on the other hand are internal. They live *inside* an Activity and are not accessed from or shared with outside applications or tasks in any way. Fragments are even not a part of application manifest and hence are not exposed outside. Android need not worry about each fragment separately, because fragment life-cycle is *bound* to that of its parent Activity. Android doesn't care what you do with fragments internally, it can just end the activity and everything inside it is destroyed as well.

Comment: I feel like most of this answer doesn't address the question. I'll try to respond to your points: 1. Setting up an activity can be done in its constructors, which can be reused by a subclass. Avoiding boilerplate is not an issue. 2. I am not suggesting that `startActvity` should be removed, but that it be possible to pass a previously constructed Activity instance instead of a class object. For other apps, it doesn't matter whether they reference a class or a constructor of some obscure package.

Comment: 3. Is there any reason backstack manipulation is not possible with an already created activity instance? 4. I can't see any relation to the question, sorry.